# Site Not Scrolling On Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

For some reason http://oxhn.com/ is not responsive on my mobile device.

I thought this was because there was this piece of CSS in my theme's stylesheet

```
html {

overflow-x: hidden;

max-width:   100%;

}
```

So I don't know what the problem is. I removed the overflow but I still am unable to scroll using any mobile device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody's clickin' yer link bro.

Comment: Try `overflow-scrolling: touch` or `overflow-scrolling: auto`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is adding `overflow: hidden` as an inline style to both the `<html>` and `<body>` elements on the page. Having looked at it on desktop and mobile I *think* it's the  `skrollr.min.js` script that is adding it. Worth removing this and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: I removed it and still having the same issue.